# Shortest possible code to produce an Exception in Kotlin?

Tags: exception, kotlin

This is sort of a fun question, but what is the shortest possible Exception producing code in Kotlin? Any Exception.

Something like:

```
throw null!!
```

which will throw an NPE.

...but hey that is still quite a long line with 12 chars.
It is actually quite usefull for testing things like logging of Exceptions in analytics and such.

Comment: I don't think saving a few characters is really going to be worth anything over `throw <wanted exception type>()`

Comment: @chris Sometimes a utility function that throws an exception is a lot more handy than writing the same long exception message several times

Comment: Btw `null!!` will already throw an exception, no need for the `throw` in front of it

Comment: @msrd0, Well sure, saving repetition on a message is perfectly fine. Trying to obfuscate code in order to throw an exception because you don't want to type the exception name isn't.

Comment: @chris But replacing the verbose `throw WhatsoeverException("descriptive message")` with `whatever()` definitely decreases readability, especially to those coming from java not familiar with kotlin type `Nothing`. Or do you think it is obvious what `map["key"] ?: whatever()` does?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an even shorter one:

```
1/0
```

It throws `java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero`.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of the number of character, you can easily declare a property which has a getter function throwing `Exception`:

```
val T: Nothing
    get() = throw Exception("For testing purpose!!")
```

<sub>Reminder: The usages of this code should probably be removed immediately after use, because it carries no meaning.</sub>

If you simply want to type less characters, I suggest to create a [Live Template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-live-templates.html) for that.

Answer (score 0):

So far the shortest I can imagine is:

```
""[1]
```

5 chars and will lead to `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=1`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind putting some utility code somewhere you can use this code:

```
e()
```

And the utility code:

```
fun e() : Nothing = throw Exception()
```

The `Nothing` return type tells the compiler that the function will never return.